# Compare patterns of bars

Tags: python, compare, comparison

I kind of know it is possible to do what I want, because I saw it (trough softwares of mass spectrometry for example).

Let's imagine I have a "bar code":

```
1,00 | 1,42 | 2,17 | 2,13
```

This bar code is a reference, let's say an object A is identified with this pattern.

If I now come up with another bar code, this time from an unidentified object:

```
1,00 | 1,40 | 2,2 | 2,10
```

Is there a way to give a "score match" for the unidentified compound ? Like, "unidentified object matches pattern A with a 95 % probability" ?

I know the question seems vague for now, but I need a starting point.

Comment: Well you compare each "section" of the bar code add see how similar they are. I don't know what you mean about probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I correct in assuming, that you have each bar given as a float describing it's 'width'? If so, you could try to compute the squared differences of A and the other object.

For your example that would be:

```
A:   1.00 | 1.42 |  2.17 | 2.13
B:   1.00 | 1.40 |  2.20 | 2.10
A-B: 0.00 | 0.02 | -0.03 | 0.03

0^2  + 0.02^2 + -0.03^2 + 0.03^2 = 0.0022
```

By squaring the differences you make sure positive and negative differences do not cancel each other out. The closest 'bar code' is the one with the minimal squared distance.

For further reading see [least squares method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).

Comment: That's a very good answer, upvote. And very easy to implement. I'll give a code example when I'm done.